# Why when i use netstat while not connected to internet, it returns some ip addresses?

Tags: ip, port, internet, netstat

I read that this command  displays network connections for the Transmission Control Protocol  more info [link netstat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat)
,but when i not connected to internet and i turn off XAMMP
server,it returns some ip:

```
PS F:\Users\ROOT> netstat -a

Active Connections

Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State   TCP   
0.0.0.0:111            ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP    
0.0.0.0:135            ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP    
0.0.0.0:445            ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP    
0.0.0.0:902            ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP    
0.0.0.0:912            ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP
0.0.0.0:1025           ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP    
0.0.0.0:1026           ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP    
0.0.0.0:1027           ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP    
0.0.0.0:1028           ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP   
0.0.0.0:1098           ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP    
0.0.0.0:2809           ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP    
0.0.0.0:3162           ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP    
0.0.0.0:11177          ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP    
0.0.0.0:46680          ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP    
127.0.0.1:1047         ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP    
127.0.0.1:1654         ROOT-PC:1655           ESTABLISHED   TCP    
127.0.0.1:1655         ROOT-PC:1654           ESTABLISHED   TCP    
127.0.0.1:8118         ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP    
127.0.0.1:8118         ROOT-PC:13259          TIME_WAIT   TCP    
127.0.0.1:8118         ROOT-PC:13260          TIME_WAIT   TCP    
127.0.0.1:8118         ROOT-PC:13271          TIME_WAIT   TCP    
127.0.0.1:8118         ROOT-PC:13278          TIME_WAIT   TCP    
127.0.0.1:8118         ROOT-PC:13280          TIME_WAIT   TCP    
127.0.0.1:8118         ROOT-PC:13285          TIME_WAIT   TCP    
127.0.0.1:8118         ROOT-PC:13287          ESTABLISHED   TCP    
127.0.0.1:8118         ROOT-PC:13288          ESTABLISHED   TCP    
127.0.0.1:13267        ROOT-PC:8118           TIME_WAIT   TCP    
127.0.0.1:13269        ROOT-PC:8118           TIME_WAIT   TCP    
127.0.0.1:13286        ROOT-PC:31620          TIME_WAIT   TCP    
127.0.0.1:13287        ROOT-PC:8118           ESTABLISHED   TCP    
127.0.0.1:13288        ROOT-PC:8118           ESTABLISHED   TCP    
127.0.0.1:13290        ROOT-PC:8118           TIME_WAIT   TCP    
127.0.0.1:31620        ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP    
192.168.86.1:139       ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP    
192.168.240.1:139      ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP    
[::]:135               ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP   
[::]:445               ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP   
[::]:1025              ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP   
[::]:1026              ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP   
[::]:1027              ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP   
[::]:1028              ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   TCP   
[::]:1098              ROOT-PC:0              LISTENING   UDP   
0.0.0.0:68             *:*   UDP    
0.0.0.0:111            *:*   UDP        
0.0.0.0:500            *:*   UDP    
0.0.0.0:3162           *:*   UDP    
0.0.0.0:4500           *:*   UDP    
0.0.0.0:5355           *:*   UDP    
0.0.0.0:11177          *:*   UDP    
127.0.0.1:1900         *:*   UDP    
127.0.0.1:51993        *:*   UDP    
127.0.0.1:61732        *:*   UDP    
127.0.0.1:64749        *:*   UDP    
192.168.86.1:137       *:*   UDP    
192.168.86.1:138       *:*   UDP    
192.168.86.1:1900      *:*   UDP    
192.168.86.1:51991     *:*   UDP    
192.168.240.1:137      *:*   UDP    
192.168.240.1:138      *:*   UDP    
192.168.240.1:1900     *:*   UDP    
192.168.240.1:51992    *:*   UDP    
[::]:500               *:*   UDP    
[::]:4500              *:*   UDP    
[::]:5355              *:*   UDP  
[::1]:1900             *:*   UDP    
[::1]:51990            *:*   UDP  
[fe80::1530:4527:9f71:8067%17]:1900  *:*   UDP   
[fe80::1530:4527:9f71:8067%17]:51988  *:*   UDP   
[fe80::7d8b:c704:eab8:f26%12]:546  *:*   UDP   
[fe80::cda6:9321:d50:51d7%18]:1900  *:*   UDP   
[fe80::cda6:9321:d50:51d7%18]:51989  *:*
```

These ips and ports and protocols, what does this mean?
I am not connected to internet!!!!

thanks for reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On windows server OS's after WinNT 4.0 SP3, this information is coming up by design.

The Winsock applications on your machine are listening (waiting for information) from those ports.

0.0.0.0 means 'all addresses'

This will come up wether you are connected to the internet or not. Think about it like this: a person has earphones in their ears, but no music is playing. They are listening, but no information is coming in.